# Show folder in List by default

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 12.04 shows folder as icon by default, see image below

[image]

How can I make folder displayed in List by default, as shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. In the top bar, do a click in *Edit*
2. Select the *Preferences* option
3. Now you'll note that the first tab (enabled by default) is called *Views*, if not, choice it
4. In this tab, the first option is *Default view*, so click in the box of the left and select *List view* instead of *Icon view*

Now when you open a new window with nautilus, you should see all the folders and files listed.

---

Set of screen-shoots to help a little bit:

[image: Step-one-and-two]
[image: Step-three]

Comment: confirm this is working in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS